# confirmed exit using trap

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to trap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal asking a confirmation from the user. The trapping part works fine. But once the signal gets trapped and the user presses `NO`, it does not return to the normal execution. Instead, it quits the script. How to make it resume execution when the user presses `no`?

Here is my code:

```shell
hell()
{
    echo "Do you want to quit? Press 1 for yes and 0 for no";
    read n;
    if [ $n == 1 ]; then
    exit 1;
    fi
}

trap "hell" SIGINT

find /
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the INT signal is being received by your script AND by your command `find /`, so it exits.

You can fully ignore the signal(s) with:

```shell
trap '' SIGNINT
```

I don't know if it's possible to catch the signal and prevent that your commands receive it.